# What word or phrase is like a more negative version of “astonished”?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a better word for the following example than *astonished*?

> I was astonished at the lack of respect Joe showed to his parents.

I’m trying to use the word *astonished* in a sentence, but I want to convey that I am surprised at a negative outcome.  Here, the lack of respect towards one’s parents is the negative part, but *astonished* is neutral, not negative.

Answer (score 6):

**Aghast:** "filled with horror or shock: *when the news came out they were aghast.*" (New Oxford American Dictionary) This is quite a strong word, but I think it fits the bill nicely.

**Dumbfounded:** "greatly astonish or amaze: *they were dumbfounded at his popularity.*" (New Oxford American Dictionary) Although it doesn't necessarily suggest a negative outcome, I think it does generally carry connotations of nonplussed bemusement.

As others have already mentioned, there's also *appalled* and *nonplussed*.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with *appalled*. I think that it’s the best word for the context you’ve given.

---

[Here’s](http://lifehacker.com/find-the-perfect-word-for-your-feelings-with-this-vocab-1653013241) an interesting diagram for you! It displays several versions of emotions. Maybe you will find it useful.

Edit: Under the category 'surprise,' the wheel lists startled, confused, amazed, excited, shocked, dismayed, disillusioned, perplexed, astonished, awe, eager, and energetic.

I apologize for not summarizing the link originally.

Answer (score 2):

*Shocked* would be appropriate. It generally has negative connotations — as opposed to *surprised*, which has positive connotations.

Comment: Hi Vicki, welcome to ELU!  Could you please fill out your answer with more “meat”? We strongly prefer longer answers with documented references, citations, and even links where possible (but not just a link, just a link to where you took your reference from if one exists). Thanks!!